# How to get value of cookie from site B from javascript running on site A

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

Imagine a chain of book stores I have a user id cookie and I want to keep the user id when the user jumps from site to site (or arrive to a site later).

I know it sounds like a security exploit so it cant be done, but both sites belong to my clients so its legal and I can add static file to the root of site B server side.

If I could add a dynamic file to site B root it was as simple as echoing the cookie value. But I can only add a static file. I was thinking of using iframe to get the file and have javascript in it that redirects to a url with the cookie value. Can I read the url of the iframe from site A ?

Any other way to do it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Wether it's legal or not is academic. It can't be done because it **could** be used illegally

Comment: possible if your both site in same domain for ex : siteA.domain.com and siteB.domain.com.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Single Sign On across multiple domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509/single-sign-on-across-multiple-domains)

Comment: Its not related to single sigh on. SSO usually involves redirections + they can use dynamic script. This is not the case.