# Integrating SSO across differents Domains using WebService?

Tags: php, codeigniter, single-sign-on

i have 3 différents domains domain-a.com and domain-b.com also domaine-c.com
and i want to use SSO, if you log in to one of these domains you have access to all other domains.

1 - using cookies is impossible because we can't share the same cookie with differents domains

2 - i'm thinking about using webservice, but i'm not good in that so i'm wondering if it's a  good solution

If you have any suggestion or recommandation or any thing Please i need you.

Comment: Here's a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/45010/3079918

Comment: see this:http://www.jasny.net/articles/simple-single-sign-on-for-php/

Comment: Thanks but i'm thinking about webservice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't share cookies but you don't need to.

Let's say your SSO runs on `sso.domain.com`

You want to log in on `a.domain.com`:

1. Make an XMLHTTPRequest request to `sso.domain.com` to check if you have a session.
2. If you have a session and are logged in you get a login `token` back.
3. You pass the `token` to application `A` with an XMLHTTPRequest. It sends a request to `sso.domain.com` to verify the token and get the user credentials.
4. You are now logged in on `a.domain.com`

This setup requires Cross-Site-Resource-Sharing to be enabled on the `sso` domain. The CORS implementation allows you to do the login process *under water*, no redirect is required.

Your an indepth look at CORS see: http://fritsvancampen.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/cross-site-origin-requests-aka-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score 0):

I use SimpleSAMLPHP.. (https://simplesamlphp.org/)

This allows me to make a single place I can ask if users a logged in. The whole thing uses SAML2 which is a secure markup language(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0).

It can be a steep learning curve to make it work but its very safe and everything is encrypted using certificates. The nice thing is that you can use all the IDP's(identity providers) you can think of. This means you can implement facebook, google etc. log-in's as well as custom log-in's.

Another great thing is that it provides SLO(single logout) as well. This will trigger log-out's in all the applications that are currently logged on..