# Best practices for token authentication in web apps?

Tags: email, web-applications, authentication

I want to make a simple REST web app, where the user interact with the objects through links in an email. The links have a token that can be used to authenticate a user without a username and password, like the ones that are usually used to reset a password.

What are the best practices for such a login-less, token-based authentication system?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am by **no** means a security expert.. but some of the points which come to mind are -

1. **Lifetime** - The token should expire after a set period of time. Indefinite access using the token certainly doesn't make sense.
2. **Replay attacks** - The mechanism should prevent replay attacks.. which means the token should be valid for not only a set period of time, but also fixed number of calls.. *Ideally* exactly 1. If this number is not exactly 1, then it opens another can of worms..

Unless, its a feature :( For example, by design, the user is expected to share link with others, and anyone with the link should be able to access the resource in question.

3. **Authorization** - Granularity of the access granted by the token. Is it black and white.. or is the token also associated with a fixed set of rights. For example - token X was issued for Read-Only access, vs token Y was issued, for same resource with R/W access.
4. **Administration** - User / Admin should be able to see and verify any currently active and issued tokens, and associated information (permissions granted / affected resource etc), and explicitly revoke them, if necessary.
5. **Secure Communication** - You should consider security of the medium through which the url with token will be sent to the user. i.e. in your scenario, do the users receive emails over secure channel (TLS / SSL)? Should the email itself be protected with DRM?
6. **Man in the Middle / Leaks** - Similarly, even though you are providing the url in email, and the user is not logging on using user name and password over SSL, the resource should still be accessed using the url with token over SSL. This will prevent any capturing of the tokens from url, by a man in the middle. You would also need to be very careful about when the users browser may use this url in places you didn't expect..

I can vaguely recall reading about a popular site being affected by their urls being used as Refer Url, when displaying ads on their website.. which means, the advertisers site would probably get the url with the token as Refer.

7. **Generation** - Choice of algorithm to generate the token - May seem pretty obvious, but the token should be extremely obscure and near impossible to guess or brute force. The tokens should never be reused and the algorithm should avoid collisions.
8. **Server Side Security** - The tokens should probably be treated with same security as you would secure users id and password. If your user database gets hacked, hackers should not get the users passwords and other sensitive information.. Similarly, if your user / resource / token database gets hacked, despite the expiration on the tokens, hackers should not be able to access the resources as users for x hours.
   Point is, when the tokens are stored on server side, they should themselves be secured / encrypted.

On the same lines.. just like its bad practice to log information like passwords in log file (specially plain text), You'd also have to consider any place these urls may get logged (plain text) on your server.. For example web server logs. If only super admins should have access to user's database, then they should also be the only ones to be able to see these token.. Not your web server admin and not any hackers parsing the log file after the hack.

9. **Auditing** - If there will be a need for auditing, you'd need some mechanism in place to prove that while the user didn't *log on* to the system, they are indeed the ones who performed the action / operation in question. Would you want to track the ip address and other information along with the request which would help such auditing?
10. **Consent** - Do your users even consent to the use of such alternate means of authentication and authorization? Should this be an optional / opt in feature?

**EDIT:** I found a [link](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/protecting-privacy-with-referrers/392382738919) to the referrer url problem I was recalling. Although it was in context of user information.

Answer (score 9):

I agree to 10 points of Vikas however from security perspective I have to tell you few points that you must be careful.

I will try to keep as simple as possible. And here I simplify the technical stuff to your special case.

Firstly tokens are used to prevent **Cross Site Request Forgery** attacks (XSRF). Keep that in your mind. If there is a web platfrom without unique tokens on the forms then any attacker can force the user to make malicious requests.

If you simply try to authenticate the user with a token, this is pretty wrong. Because there must be no simple authentication process and you can not rely on token.

Here is how the login system works in official security documentations, im writing as I remember:

**Identification**: you have to identify the user firstly, that is generally done with username. YOu will know that there is a user exist in your system.

**Authentication**: Let's say you have already identified that user A want to login. So you mast authenticate the user A with something that you know and user A know. We call it password simply :) You cannot by pass this step with plain text methods. Passwords are generally encrypted in your db and also through all communication with secure certicates, check ssl.

**Authorization**: okay you made the authentication somehow, the user has a right to get Authorization. Let's say if the admin type user is logged in, he has differen rigts and if the normal user is logged in then she has regular rights.

**Session control**: finally you have to control the session with a secure way. Here generally in web applciations people use access tokens for all requests to be sure that the authorized user is aware of the request. As a platform owner you are responsible to secure everything until the session ends. If you don't satisfy the users with your security, then probably your platf is not going to survive longer.

**Tokens** have different **lifetime** to expire and different **access rights**.

Now let's look at what facebok like companies do with mobile aplications. For the mobile app they generate a unique access token which is alway alive. One shortcoming here is, if any attacker steal the mobile token generally she can do anything in the account anytime :) Anyway here our point is how they verify the users with those tokens; firstly the token is unique for that device. (Actually not exactly unique or not dependent on hardware, because if you clearly steal the necessary files from the device then you can use it on another phone). So with this unique access token which is generated with users password at their initial login on mobile app, they can login always automatically with that. And this method is a little similar to what you want to do. However pay attention that they don't authenticate the users with links or email code.

**Verification is not an authentication**, don't forget that. By sending e-mail you can verify the users if the emailed code is unique and valid for only 30 sec or 1 minute. I hope you got the point.

Here I suggest you to check **single sign on** across multiple domains, which is really interesting.
[Single Sign On across multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509/single-sign-on-across-multiple-domains?lq=1)
Let's say you are logged in to google.com and then you visit the youtube.com Opps the youtube is already logged in? Yea, cool right, but exist for long time. They can authenticate users accross domains which use different cookies with a little and secure trick. You will read on the link.

If your service is not really confidential and if you want to make your users happy with easy login system. Here is **two** of my **solutions** which I love :)

1-) Ask users their email address: just directly send 4-6 digit code as e-mail. Ask user the enter/click on that. There will be no password at all, only unique code on each login.

2-) Let's say you need to verify the user with a stronger way than email. Then mobile phone :) Here trick is; you will not send the verification code to user, but they will send what you tell them to you.
Ask to user to send a SMS with a unique CODE to XXXXXX your number :) Connect your mobile operator with your web service and check whether the code is sent to you by the user :)

There is always a trade-off between security and simplicity, and also with complexity. You have to find the balance.

*Don't try to make it simple if your security is going away.*

*Don't try to make it complex if it'll seem more secure.*

Hope those informationn help you.