# How to authenticate in satellizer for other sub-domain?

Tags: php, laravel, satellizer

I am trying to authenticate in satellizer for other domain, say I am in a abc.main.com and I want to authenticate xyz.main.com as well along with abc.main.com by providing single time username and password.username and password for both domain is same.

I am trying like this

```
        //$location.path("abc.main.com").replace().reload(true);
        if(window.location.host == "abc.main.com"){
          window.location.host = "xyz.main.com";
          $auth.login({email: email,password: password}).then(function(data) {
            console.log("xyz login success");
          });
        }
        window.location.host = "abc.main.com"; 
        // continue to abc login
```

Is it possible ? If yes please help

Thanks,

Comment: this link would be helpful please check with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509/single-sign-on-across-multiple-domains