# "Single sign-on" using existing ASP.NET user store

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, single-sign-on, asp.net-4.5

(Using inverted commas because I don't think this is strictly a single sign-on use case. Although it's the same concept.)

I have an existing `ASP.NET Web Forms` site (`SiteA`) using `Membership`...

Web.config:

```
<machineKey validationKey="etc"
    decryptionKey="etc"
    validation="SHA1"
    decryption="AES" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="goodcookie"
        loginUrl="~/login"
        timeout="2880"
        defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>

<membership>
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="etc"
            applicationName="etc" />
    </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="etc"
            applicationName="etc"
            name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Login button's codebehind:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUsername.Value, txtPassword.Value))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Value, true);
    Response.RedirectToRoute("home");
}
```

Master page's codebehind for each page load:

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("/login", true);
}
```

There's a requirement to create a new site (`SiteB`) on a separate domain, however both `SiteA` and `SiteB` will use the same database.

Some users will only have access to `SiteA`, some only to `SiteB`, and some to both `SiteA` and `SiteB`. This will be determined by their role(s).

I've created `SiteB` with identical values in `Web.config` (same cookie name, same machine key, etc). Even the same application name just to test. Of course I'm able to log in to both sites with the same user credentials, but.. if I'm logged in to `SiteA`, and I load `SiteB`, it will behave like I'm not authenticated (ie. redirect me to the login page).

What could I be missing?

(Will edit if I think of any more relevant details)

Answer (score 0):

Different domains cannot read coookies of each other and thus if you logged in to `SiteA` the authentication cookie isn't sent when you request `SiteB`. But different subdomains can share cookies so moving sites to single domain should be a solution. Also read this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509/single-sign-on-across-multiple-domains) for more information.